# Move CSS out of JavaScript file and into CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following JavaScript code with inline CSS.

```
var container = display.getContainer();
container.style.cssText = 'width:100%;height:100%;z-index:100;object-fit: contain;';
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

I would like to move the inline CSS to the following class in style.css

```
.containerClass {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:100;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

I have tried the following:

`container.addClass('containerClass');`

I've been unable to articulate my problem correctly, thus am having trouble finding the precise solution I am after.

Further -how would I go about telling the JavaScript file about the location of `.containerClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** The ***classList*** property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9.

The following code will work in all browsers -

```js
function addClass() {
  var element, name, arr;
  element = document.getElementById("container");
  name = "mystyle";
  arr = element.className.split(" ");
  if (arr.indexOf(name) == -1) {
    element.className += " " + name;
  }
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

div {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Add Class" button to add the "mystyle" class to the container element:</p>

<button onclick="addClass()">Add Class</button>

<div id="container">This is a DIV element.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In you style.css, define the properties for `.containerClass`.

style.css :

```
.containerClass {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:100;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

When you want to add this styling, just add that class to the element you want to using javascript.
Javascript:

```
var container = document.getElementById("elementId");
container.classList.add("containerClass");
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Now how to I tell the JS file how to find that class in the CSS file?

Comment: You don't need to tell anything to javascript. Say for example you want to add `.containerClass` to a `<div id="someId">...</div>`. After running the above code, the div will become `<div id="someId" class="containerClass">...</div>` and the style will be automatically applied.

Comment: Just don't forget to include you style.css in your html file.